# Consumed Time of System.out.println(); Java statement?

Tags: java, debugging, monitoring

I hear that the `System.out.println();` Java statement is costly (it consumes a lot of time)
So I try to evaluate its cost:
When I evaluate 5 statements... `The cost = 1.0`
So I expect the cost of 1 statement = 0.2
But actually I found `The cost = 0.0` !!

```
double t1 = 0;
double t2 = 0;

t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("aa");
System.out.println("aa");
System.out.println("aa");
System.out.println("aa");
System.out.println("aa");
t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("The cost = " + (t2-t1) ); 
// The cost = 1.0 


t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("aa");
t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("The cost = " + (t2-t1) ); 
// The cost = 0.0 
// Expected : 1.0/5 = 0.2 -- But Actual : 0.0
```

Why that?

Comment: You should increase the count of calls in your benchmark to something like 5000 in a loop. **Then** you probably will get a better output!

Comment: Issue is in your code, not in `system.out.println`.

Comment: You do know that even one millisecond is damn costly as a normal cpu can handle a few million instructions in that time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`System#currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) returns `long` and not `double`. Thus you're loosing `.2`.

Testing 5 statements is not a good idea, specially when you almost don't feel the time it takes to perform it. I advise you to have more than 5 statements to test and then reduce the amount to something more than 1 as well.

You want to do a precise measurements time, it's better to use [`System#nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29), since it gives time in *nano seconds*:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

Look for "nanoTime vs currentTimeMillis" and you'll get hundreds of articles.

Comment: Would you also educate on the difference between `currentTimeMillis` and `nanoTime`? Then I can skip an own attempt at answering yet another invalid benchmarking question :)

Answer (score 3):

When i tested your code, the output is always 0.0. Pls try your benchmark with `System.nanoTime();`
Or do it with more `System.out.println()`

```
    double t1 = 0;
    double t2 = 0;

    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
        System.out.println("aa");
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The cost = " + (t2-t1) ); 


    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        System.out.println("aa");
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The cost = " + (t2-t1) );
```

Output: 62.0 and 5.0

And this difference of 1.2 ms is because the loop gets faster while runtime.

Answer (score 3):

If the execution time is less than one millisecond, you will see nothing, because the clock hasn't 'ticked' yet. For this type of micro benchmarking, you should use something like:

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime()
```

for your time measurements. (this measures time in nanosecond units, although not always with that much granularity)

Answer (score 1):

Also, the time to complete System.out.println will be different on a more or less powerful computer, and how busy that computer is performing other tasks at that particular moment.